# Remote Desktop Connection Manager throws an error when logging off a group

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote-desktop, rdc-manager

I'm using Microsoft's [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047&displaylang=en) on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. I have several groups of servers, all under a single parent, sharing domain credentials.

Some of my groups can be logged off as a group, using the option "Log off group". But, one of my newer groups cannot be logged off as a group. I have some servers that cannot even be logged off individually from the "Log off server" option. I have to use the Logoff command from inside the guest.

> `Unable to log off from <group>`
>   `Reason: Unable to enumerate remote sessions`

Comment: If you run shutdown -l /f and then reboot, you might be able to log off normally..

Comment: I can logoff of the guest from the Start Menu > Logoff. I cannot logoff using the command from the RDC Manager tool.

Comment: I don't think it is just windows 7 - I have the same problem with Windows Server 2008 (not R2)

Comment: I'm thinking Remote Desktop Services has something to do with it... I'm not a server guy, check your "Roles". http://goo.gl/NG5zJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "servers" that cannot be logged off individually or as a group using the RDC Manager menu options are Windows 7 machines. The "servers" that *do* logoff properly are Windows Server 2008 R2.

So, for now, it seems like Windows 7 is the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can log odd server 2012/2008 but not window 7 machines, do you know if there is a fix? I have seen that you have to be domain admin or run as administrator but I am domain admin and have tried running as admin but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears when using multiple domains, as logoff will try to list sessions with the user that launched the app.

[There's no workaround until MS gives one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/222e7585-7389-41e7-ad5a-5307048fdbf0/remote-desktop-manager-quotunable-to-enumerate-remote-sessionsquot).